What is the meaning of "Your horse isn't much of a shot."?
What is the meaning of "Your horse isn't much of a shot."?

It is from the movie "Out of Africa".
The script is in here
She(the lion) wanted to see if you'd run. That's how they decide. A lot like people.
She almost had me for lunch!
It wasn't her fault. She's a lion.
It wasn't mine.
Doesn't that outfit come with a rifle?               
It's on my saddle.
Better keep it with you.
Your horse isn't much of a shot.

Thank you.

It's no use leaving the rifle on the saddle (with the horse): it can't shoot at all. Saying "Your horse isn't much of a shot" is wry humour. When someone is a "good shot" it means they are an expert with a gun.

And part of the humor is that it's not saying a horse is unable to shoot a gun but that a horse is likely to miss the target.

Weather Vane, TimR,  I thank you for your comments.

It's sarcastic.
"Not much of a shot" means the subject isn't very good at shooting a gun.
The rider is asked if their outfit - what they are wearing - includes a gun. They reply that the gun is attached to the horse's saddle, so it is in fact the horse that is 'wearing' the gun.
So, the comment that the horse isn't good at shooting sarcastically means that the person should be carrying the gun, not the horse.

Astralbee, I thank you for the answer.  It is hard to catch the sarcasm.

That's from meaning 5 from this definition of "shot": "One who shoots; especially: Marksman." Especially when combined with adjectives like "good" or "poor," it speaks of shooting skill. See also the definition of "not much of a", "used to say that someone or something is not very good."
"Not much of a shot" = "not a very good shot" = "not good at shooting with accuracy." And the humorous meaning is that the horse has no use for the gun since it can't use it well.

Andy Bonner, I appreciate your answer.  I knew the meaning of 'not much of', but I was not sure what meaning of shot would be applied here.  The subject is a horse.  I wonder if I, as a non-native speaker, would ever be able to understand these kinds of remarks in a fast-moving movie conversation.
